# pseudo code to find the numbers which appear more than once in a list

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode, series

I have a series like `1,2,199,100,8,100,199,1001,5,9` and I got to write a pseudo code to find out the numbers which appear more then once in the above list. I can clearly see that 199 and 100 appear twice in the list and that should be the answer but how should I write the pseudocode for it? 
My logic is something like this:

```
   array x = {1,2,199,100,8,100,199,1001,5,9}
   array y
   array j
for(int i = 0;i< 9; i++){
 if x[i] exists in y
     j[i] = y
 else
    y[i] = x


}
```

Comment: @TomasNarros what i have tried is there in the question.. cannot think of much further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the list with quick sort or merge sort (n log n) then do a single pass over the list comparing the current number to the previous O(n). If the previous number equals the current then you have a duplicate.

EDIT:

```
Array array = {1,2,199,100,8,100,199,1001,5,9}
Array sorted = sort(array)
for (int i=1; i<sorted.length; i++)
    int p = sorted[i-1]
    int c = sorted[i]
    if (p==c) print "duplicate"
```

Comment: can you please write a snippet of pseudo code for that?

Answer (score 1):

With the exists() check this looks like it would have the same performance as a bubble sort. It would probably be faster if you sorted the array (with a faster sort) then did one extra pass to identify the dupes. 
If I understand your pseudo code correctly it seems to have a bug. Shouldn't it be more like:

```
for(int i = 0;i< 9; i++){
 if x[i] exists in y
     j.push(x[i]);
 else
    y.push(x[i]);    

}
```

Comment: yes you are right! it should be it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// loop through list of numbers
    // count apperences in list
    // if appearences > 1
            // remove all instances, add to results list

// print the results list -- this will have all numbers that appear more than once.
```

Comment: what about the second line? how to count the appearances?

Comment: whatever language you're using most likely has a method to do so.  things like that i don't go into detail with in psuedocode.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're restricted to only using primitive types rather than being able to use `java.util.Collections`, you could work it like this:

```
For each value in `x`
  Grab that value
  If the list of duplicates does not contain that value
    See if that value reoccurs at a later index in `x`
      If it does, add it to the list of duplicates
```

Here's the pseudocode translated to Java:

```
private void example() {
    int [] x = new int [] {1,2,199,100,8,100,199,1001,5,9, 199};
    int [] duplicates = new int[x.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      int key = x[i];
      if (!contains(duplicates, key)) {
        // then check if this number is a duplicate
        for (int j = i+1; j < x.length-1; j++) {
          // start at index i+1 (no sense checking same index as i, or before i, since those are alreayd checked
          // and stop at x.length-1 since we don't want an array out of bounds exception
          if (x[j] == key) {
            // then we have a duplicate, add to the list of duplicates
            duplicates[i] = key;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < duplicates.length; n++) {
      if (duplicates[n] != 0) {
        System.out.println(duplicates[n]);
      }
    }
}

  private boolean contains(int [] array, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] == key) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```